# Mac Mini (2018) font is blurry on Samsung Syncmaster 2494HM

Tags: mac, fonts, hdmi, dvi, mac-mini

I have recently purchased a Mac Mini (2018 Model), and connected it to my [Samsung SyncMaster 2494HM LCD monitor](https://www.samsung.com/ca/support/model/LS24KIQRBQ/XAC/) via [HDMI to DVI cable](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B014I8UQJY). The video output was far from optimal, and text especially was fuzzy and blurry. In the beginning, I was using HDMI-HDMI, and the switch to DVI had no visible effect.

Here is an example:

[image: Sample Screenshot]

The picture quality was fine when the monitor was connected to a W
indows 10 PC. Here are the steps I have taken:

I tried enabling font smoothing, which helped in the mac menu's, but didn't do anything in other applications. I disabled AV mode in my monitor settings. I set my monitor resolution to scaled at 1920 x 1080. I tried DVI-HDMI, DVI-USB-C, and HDMI-HDMI connections.

I am running macOS Catalina. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Looks normal to me. macOS’ font rendering is no longer suitable for low DPI. I think there was a question about that somewhere...

Comment: @DanielB I just realized the attached screenshot looks fine on any device other than mine, I will upload an update picture soon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple is less concerned about non-Retina displays (like yours) these days. This also means that unfortunately font rendering is quite bad on these by default.

According to various sources around the net ([here’s one](http://osxdaily.com/2018/09/26/fix-blurry-thin-fonts-text-macos-mojave/)), you can improve the situation by issuing the following command in Terminal:

```
defaults write -g CGFontRenderingFontSmoothingDisabled -bool NO
```

You have to log out and back in again for the setting to take effect.

Keep in mind though that Apple has long since used a different approach to font rendering compared to Microsoft. Microsoft basically snaps to pixels whenever possible, accepting that the result may be inaccurate while providing a crisp look and better readability, especially with small font sizes/low DPI. Apple does not snap to pixels but uses the correct geometry, even if it results in blurry fonts.

Typography is complicated.

Comment: Thanks, the command helped, but it's still not perfect.

Comment: I had the blurry font issue with a brand new Macbook Pro 16 (late 2019) running Catalina. Smoothing commands results vary between blurry and extra bright fonts.
I finally sent back the computer to Apple and went back on Ubuntu. This issue is totally unacceptable.